# Изменение размера изображения до выгрузки на сервер

Tags: javascript, fileupload, файлы

Есть изображение выбранное с помощью `input type="file"`.
Как изменить размер изображения на стороне клиента до выгрузки его на сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается [так](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/). Учтите, что для подобных манипуляций браузер должен поддерживать HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать библиотеку [FileAPI](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/#example), то это будет выглядеть так:

```
<input id="choose" type="file" name="files[]" />
<script>
FileAPI.event.on(choose, 'change', function (evt){
    FileAPI.upload({
        url: '...',
        files: evt.target,
        imageTransform: {
            maxWidth: 800,
            maxHeight: 600
        },
        complete: function (err, result){

        }
    });
});
</script>
```